# Update dictionary while iterating

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a way to update a dictionary during an iteration in order to avoid the  `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` ?

What I am trying to do is poping some keys in inner dictionaries if a condition is accomplished. For intance given the following dictionary:

```
D = {'a': {'s': 1,'b': 2}, 's': {'a': -1, 'c': 3}, 'b': {'z': 2, 'x': 4, 'a': -2}}
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
D = {'a': {'s': 1,'b': 2}, 's': {'c': 3}, 'b': {'z': 2, 'x': 4}}
```

Note that in `'s'` and `'b'` dictionary values `'a'` key is gone in inner dictionaries because there is already a value `a` key in D whose has `'s'` and `'b'` as values.

What I tried so far:

```
for k, v in D.items():
    for i, j in v.items():
        if i in D and k in D[i]:
            D.pop(i)
```

The condition should check if in a inner dictionary let's say `'s'` inner dictionary already has a `'key'` which is actually a `'key'` of `D` dictionary. There is no order considered here. So in `'s'` inner dictionary `'a'` should be removed cause there is a `D['a']` which actually has an `'s'` in inner dictionary. The same logic holds for `'b'` inner dictionary, since there is an `'a'` `key` in inner `'b'` and `D['a']` has `'b'`, I would to remove `'a'` from `D['b']` and just keep `D['a']['b']`

But that would lead me to pop items that I want to preserve. Since I am planning to work with a big dictionary of dictionaries what would be the best option here?

Comment: Please, clarify what condition you want to check. I mean, your `if` statement looks weird.

Comment: Why does your desired result have `{'a': {'s': 1,'b': 2}` but you also say `So in 's' inner dictionary 'a' should be removed`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove each entry in the inner dictionaries of D for which the key has already been defined in D. Note that you're treating the dictionary as an ordered sequence here, even though a Python dictionary is inherently un-ordered.

Instead of trying to modify the existing dictionary while iterating over it, create a new dictionary and append values to it in the `for` loop.

Working implementation:

```
D = {'a': {'s': 1,'b': 2}, 's': {'a': -1, 'c': 3}, 'b': {'z': 2, 'x': 4, 'a': -2}}
newdict = {}

for k_outer,v_outer in D.items():
    newdict[k_outer] = {}
    for k_inner,v_inner in v_outer.items():
        if k_inner not in newdict.keys():
            newdict[k_outer][k_inner] = v_inner

print(newdict)
D = newdict
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'s': 1, 'b': 2}, 's': {'c': 3}, 'b': {'z': 2, 'x': 4}}
```

Or if you absolutely want to modify D on the fly, then use `.copy()` which allows you to iterate over a copy of the original dictionary while modifying the original dictionary inside the loop:

```
D = {'a': {'s': 1,'b': 2}, 's': {'a': -1, 'c': 3}, 'b': {'z': 2, 'x': 4, 'a': -2}}

seen = []

for k_outer,v_outer in D.copy().items():
    seen.append(k_outer)
    for k_inner,v_inner in v_outer.copy().items():
        if k_inner in seen:
            D[k_outer].pop(k_inner)

print(D)
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'s': 1, 'b': 2}, 's': {'c': 3}, 'b': {'z': 2, 'x': 4}}
```